# Is it possible to add two or more subreports with different connection strings in main Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my main report I add subreports with this code...

```
ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument(); 
rpt.Load(_mainReportPath);

CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.Section sec = rpt.ReportClientDocument.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections[0]; 

rpt.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreport("Sub-Report-A.rpt",
        _subreportAPath, sec);
rpt.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreport("Sub-Report-B.rpt",
        _subreportBPath, sec);
```

And this works.

Now I need to add new subreports with different connection strings. Is this possible? (maybe with DataBaseLogon...)

I am new in CRs.
Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the extent I know its possible but it may impact performance of the report.

Comment: What do you mean by "impact performance of the report"? The thing is that I have a main report and I need to insert a footer and header subreports which have info from companies and partners, several stored procedures from different servers. And off course main report has it own source. If you have an example, I would be very thankful. I tried to load each subreport separately and to define conn string for it, but I got error message: This is not supported with subreports.

Comment: actually I work on CR as a standalone application... Coming to performance part if CR is made to retrive from different conections then report can become slow as it need to connect to different databases.

Comment: Yes, I though so, that it would make an effect on the speed. But, do you know the way to define connection for subreport via c# code when I load it?

Comment: @Ferid Sorry to say I don't have expertise to work on CR using C#, If you have any query in standalone then I can try to help